# use function or var to create a data frame column/index name

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, pandas

I've got a series of loops that calculate sales for different brands, different periods from different dataframes.
And here is the part of the code I want to optimize:

```
#shname,dep,lname,y - come from itterables

var=shname+dep+'ytd'+lname
if dep == 'PY': ytd=data.loc[(Data.Brand==lname) & (Data['PY_YTD?']==True),['Sales']].sum()
if dep == 'NY': ytd=data.loc[(Data.Brand==lname) & (Data['NY_YTD?']==True),['Sales']].sum()
exec('%s=%d' % (var,ytd))
```

as you see there is a column name that happens to be different in dataframes depending on report year (PY - present, NY- next):

```
Data['PY_YTD?']==True
Data['NY_YTD?']==True
```

so I simply used IF. However I wonder if there is a way to use some kind of function that calculates the column name based on currently iterated value

I imagine it should look something like this:

```
def YEAR (y):
    if y = 'PY': return Data['PY_YTD?']==True
    if y = 'NY': return Data['NY_YTD?']==True

ytd=data.loc[(Data.Brand==lname) & (YEAR(var)),['Sales']].sum()s
```

would appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you can just insert `var` into a larger string:

```
data.loc[
   (Data.Brand == lname) & Data['{}_YTD?'.format(var)],   # var + '_YTD?'
   ['Sales']
].sum()
```